# Spring data get unique values of group by

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have the following records in my MongoDB database and I will get only the years. e.g. if I have:

```
ID   year ...
1   "2016" ...
2   "2016" ...
3   "2017" ...
4   "2016" ...
5   "2018" ...
```

then I will get:

```
2016
2017
2018
```

as result. Is this somehow possible with Spring Data with method name (I havn't seen GroupBy for methods) or with @Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue the **[`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** command to get the desired result. In mongo shell, run the following:

```
db.collection.distinct("year")
```

In SpringData, you need to use the `@Autowired` annotation to bring in the base `MongoTemplate` from spring-data-mongodb

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

You can then use the `mongoTemplate` instance to query the underlying collection as

```
List<String> coll = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName").distinct("year");
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to do it with @Query or with the method name?

Comment: @user3318489 Not that I know of unfortunately.

Comment: There is `findDistinct...` methods but they throw away duplicate *docments*. You want to do this based on one specific field